# Get the value by index over JSON object in C#

Tags: c#, json

I have this JSON string which is part of very long string:

```
string UserConfigTemps =
{"prodStatus":{"uservalue":"1","ismodified":"false"},
"experimentation":{"uservalue":"2","ismodified":"true"}}
```

I convert it to a JSON object by

```
var  configinterface = JObject.Parse(UserConfigTemps);
```

Now my problem is here, I want to get the value of `ismodified` like this

```
foreach(var temps in configinterface )
{
    if(configinterface[temps].ismodified) // do somthing
}
```

I don't want to write `configinterface[prodStatus].ismodified` because it will be very long.

Comment: Then rename `configinterface` to `i` and `prodStatus` to `p` and you can write `i[p]`. But you obviously shouldn't do that, because it harms the readability of your code. What is your question? Anyway you're already in a `foreach()`, so you should operate on `temps` instead of `configinterface[temps]`.

Comment: *because it will be very long*, well welcome to programming my friend. Length of code is not something you should be concerned about (well, at least for something this short)

Comment: I have 1000 values in the json string, do you want from me to write 1000 lines of code to do this operation !!!!

Comment: You may want to add some example code. Can you get the code to work on [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net)?

Comment: You shouldn't be writing 1000 lines of anything, no matter how long the code line is. Sounds like you have an XY problem here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest would be, using a traversing the resulting `JObject`

```
string jsonString = "your json string";
JObject o = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
foreach (var p in o) {
    if (p.Value.Value<bool>("ismodified")) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

See the docs of [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) for details

**EDIT**

Probably you should define a custom class anyways

```
class Config {
    public string uservalue {get;set;}
    public bool ismodified {get;set}
}

var c = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Config>>(jsonString);
foreach (var x in c) {
    if (x.Value.ismodified) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my soltion,

```
string UserConfigTemps =
{"prodStatus":{"uservalue":"1","ismodified":"false"},
"experimentation":{"uservalue":"2","ismodified":"true"}};
var  ConfigInterface = JObject.Parse(UserConfigTemps);
Dictionary<string, Object> jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Object>>(UserConfigTemps);
foreach (var item in jsonObj)
{  
if(configinterface[item.Key]["ismodified"].ToString()=="true");
}
```

Comment: What do you need the additonal dictionary for? `JObject` is also an `IEnumerable` thus, you can traverse it.

Comment: I use a dictionary to avoid using  configinterface[prodStatus]["ismodified"]

Comment: Well, you CAN do it this way. See my answer for an easier way.

Comment: Yes, your solution is better. Thank you.